# How many values of $x$ from $1$ to $100$ satisfy $x^2 - x\lfloor x \rfloor = 86.25$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I found the following problem from *Brilliant* site.

> How many values of $x$ from $1$ to $100$ satisfy $x^2 - x\lfloor x \rfloor = 86.25$?

I divides both sides by $x$ to get $$x - \lfloor x \rfloor = \dfrac{86.25}{x}$$

This tells us that $x - \lfloor x \rfloor \in (0,1)$ and so $\frac{86.25}{x} \in (0,1)$.  We also know that $x \in (86.25, 100)$ since both $86.25$ and $100$ don't satisfy the equation.  However, I can't seem to find the elementary approach for this problem.

Comment: Last time I checked, this is the Level 5 qualifying problem for Algebra over at brilliant.org. Is that where you got it from? (I hope not, because that would be cheating..)

Comment: Welcome to Brilliant, @NasuSama. You are encouraged to work on these problems yourself, to figure out how to think and approach them. If you ask others for help, then the problems will become too difficult for you to work on / understand.

Comment: @Calvin The statement "if you ask for help then the problems will become too difficult" is one of the most bizarre pedagogical remarks that I have ever encountered. What do you mean by that strange remark?

Comment: @BillDubuque Our system gives you harder problems as you successfully solve (and conversely, easier problems if you answer wrongly). As such, if you game it by asking your 'friends', you can place yourself in a scenario where you cannot reasonably do any problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $f(x)$ be $x^2-\lfloor x \rfloor x$. For each interval $I_n=(n,n+1), n \in \mathbb N$, the function $f$ is continuous and increasing in $I_n$, and $f(I_n)=(0,n+1)$, so the equation is satisfied by exactly one value of $x$ of each interval $I_n$ for $86\leq n\leq99$. That is fourteen values.

Comment: +1 This is the approach that I used, and follows easily from the given properties. It avoids any tedious counting / tracking down of exact values.

Comment: As did I, months ago when I joined ;)

Answer (score 3):

Write $k=\lfloor x\rfloor$.  Then $x=k+\alpha$ where $0\le\alpha<1$.  The equation becomes
$$(k+\alpha)^2-(k+\alpha)k=86.25$$
which simplifies to
$$\alpha^2+k\alpha-86.25=0\ .$$
We need to find $k$ such that this quadratic has a solution for $\alpha$ with $0\le\alpha<1$.  By considering the graph of the quadratic $p(t)=t^2+kt-86.25$ and noting that $p(0)$ is negative, there will be a root between $0$ and $1$ if and only if $p(1)>0$, that is,
$$k>85.25\ .$$
Since $k$ is an integer and for your problem $k<100$, the possible values of $k$ are from $86$ to $99$ and there are $14$ of them.  Each of them gives one value of $\alpha$ and one value of $x$.  So there are $14$ values of $x$.

Answer (score 0):

$x^2 - x\lfloor x \rfloor = 86.25$

Let $n = \lfloor x \rfloor, \delta = x - \lfloor x \rfloor$

Then $(n + \delta)^2 - (n + \delta) n = 86.25$

And $\delta^2 + n \delta - 86.25 = 0$

Hence $\delta = \dfrac{-n \pm \sqrt{n^2 + 345}}{2}$

So we want $n$ such that $\sqrt{n^2 + 345} - n \lt 2$

i.e. $n^2 + 345 \lt (n+2)^2$

$ \Rightarrow 0\lt 4n - 341$

$ \Rightarrow n > 85.25$

And $x = n + \dfrac{\sqrt{n^2 + 345
}- n}{2} = \dfrac{n + \sqrt{n^2 + 345}}{2} $